# They were split into half or halves?

Tags: grammar, singular-vs-plural

> Assuming I saw a group of people, for instance 10 people and
> accidentally there was a sharp wire that split their bodies
> horizontally and each person is split in two separate parts. So
> there would be 20 parts now since there were 10 people.

From the example above, if I wish to report the event, which sentence is correct between these:

1. They were split into half.
2. They were split into halves.
3. They were split in two separate parts.

**This is my view**: since the object is plural (10 people) although it's **a group** of people, in my opinion as an ESL learner, I'm confused between considering them as a group as in one quantity i.e. a group of people or ten distinct *objects*, let's say they are all passengers in a ship.

Furthermore, the third point above, in my way of thinking is more like there were **10 people** and the group was divided into two separate parts or two new groups i.e. each group there are 5 people. And this, to me, doesn't tell the reader that their bodies were gone wrong.

In case you are asking *why that example?*, I'm intending to make a review of a horror movie "Ghost Ship" and I'm stuck at the part telling about the scene when the passengers are killed by the wire. I hope that makes sense. Please also give another suggestion if none of those sounds grammatical.

Comment: This has been asked before on ELU - ["Cut into halves" vs. "cut in half"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83247/cut-into-halves-vs-cut-in-half) 
 and ["Please, cut the apple in halves." or "Please, cut it in half."?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/193169/please-cut-the-apple-in-halves-or-please-cut-it-in-half) Short answer: all combinations of the prepositions ***in / into*** and singular / plural ***half / halves*** are "valid", but *cut something **in half*** is by far the most common form.

Comment: They were split in two. They could only be halves if split from top to bottom, which would be unlikely if ten people are split by the same wire.

Comment: In Britain, if not elswhere, if someone's body is divided, e.g. in a accident, bomb attack, murder by axe, run over by train, etc, we would commonly say they were '**cut** in two'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many people in the comments have given great suggestions:

- they were (all) cut in two
- they were (all) split in two
- they were (all) split in half
- they were (all) cut in half
- they were split into two halves

Using "all" helps remove ambiguities regarding the group being split into two, so it's better to use that.

> **@FumbleFingers**
>
> all combinations of the prepositions ***in / into*** and singular / plural ***half / halves*** are "valid", but cut something in half is by far the most common form.
>
> [Cut into halves vs cut in half](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83247/cut-into-halves-vs-cut-in-half)
>
> [Please cut the apple in halves or please cut in half](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/193169/please-cut-the-apple-in-halves-or-please-cut-it-in-half)